# can we fetch API data and show data on Flutter local notification while the user closes the app?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to show api data on flutter local notification after app gets closed.

I tried workmanger, I am working on adding a workmanager flutter to my project along with flutter local notification. I don't want to use firebase.

Comment: You can add timer for it

Answer (score 0):

so you can schedule the notification using

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule()
```

and it receive

> scheduledDate

so you can add this scheduled date after user closes the app using app lifecycle, hope this helping

Comment: Thank you for your response, I want to show local notifications periodically, at certain periods of time, after app get closed.

Comment: can I add API inside flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyshow method ?